# IOS6 Update view when interface orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, ios6

I need to reposition a UIPopoverController when interface orientation change. In io5 I just did everything in:`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

I know I can listen to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` in IOS6, but I only want interface orientation calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas behind ios6 rotation are that some views, like popovers, dont really have an orientation. as they dont fill the screen.

To re-layout the view as the size of the popover changes layout your view in `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` in your popover's content view controller and ajust the views as needed to the new size. Animatable changes are animated.